# Survey Monkey results directly into DB

Tags: oracle, plsql

This may be a question for Survey Monkey, but I felt that someone here may have encountered something like this in past experiences. Is there a way to work with the API of Survey Monkey (SM), to add the information from the survey straight into a database of my own? I realize that I can generate the information into output files, but I was wondering if there was a way to directly access the information from the SM database. I feel like this might cause some privacy concerns for SM. Has anyone attempted this, or would the best option of mine be to create my own surveys without a third party website?

Comment: Yes, most probably: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/ but you may want to specify what database you're using - mysql or oracle.

Comment: I'm going to be using oracle.

Comment: I have looked into zapier, which uses MS sql and survey monkey to add new survey responses into the database, however I was looking to develop my own application that does this instead of using a third party site. Does anyone have any resources that may lead me in the right direction in using the Survey Monkey API to extract the response data and then to move it into a database?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and here's my solution.
I was doing health related surveys which contain HIPPA protected Personal Health Info. Zapier is NOT HIPAA safe, so the "zap the results over to Google Drive" solution didn't work.

So I wanted a quick n dirty way to grab SM survey data and begin to design a data structure to analyse and store this data. I figured that I would start with <1000 results, sort it out, then build out a bigger/fancier structure as needed.

I just downloaded CSV's of the SM individual responses, munged the downloaded CSV files to make a Python CSV reader happy, then wrote a Python 3.5 script to grab the survey data and spit it out into a couple of output CSV files designed for different analytic purposes.

It was really quick and easy to alter the Python script to deliver different subsets of data to different output files, and really quick and easy to see if these output (CSV or XLS) files really told me what I wanted to know.

This is a really quick and easy way to start analysing right away without spending too much time on procedural overhead.  You can alter CSV (or XLS ) tables really quickly and easily, so you can mix and match data / derivative data as much as you want.  A wise person once told me "don't think, do." So the more you analyse on small runs of data, the better your final Big Buildout In The Sky will look.

Yah, you can spend a lot of time writing and API and setting up a dbase, but if you are not completely happy with what you want out of the SM data, start small.  Hope this helps.